# Capital M is encountered, duplicate previous character (then remove the M), and capital N is encountered remove the next character from the string

Tags: python, string

- Whenever a capital 'M' is encountered, duplicate the previous character (then remove the 'M')
- Whenever a capital 'N' is encountered remove the next character from the string (then remove the 'N').
- All other characters in the string will be lowercase letters.
- For example: "abcNdgM" should return "abcgg". The final string will never be empty.

```py
def StringChanges(str):
    str2 = []
    list = ""

    for i in str:
        if i == 'M':
            str2.pop(i)
            str -= 1
            i -= 1
        elif i == 'N':
            if i == list - 1:
                str2.pop()
        else:
             str2.append(i)
             list -= 2
             i -= 2
    return ''.join(str2)

str = "oMoMkkNrrN"

print(StringChanges(str))
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have a string,  and if find "M", duplicate the previous character and delete "M", and if find N delete the next character. for example abcNdgM" should return "abcgg". or oMoMkkNrrN should return oMoMkkNrrN.

Comment: Alright thanks for explaining, so what's the issue, what do you want the output to be and what is the output.

Comment: You should check the lines with “-=“  - not all of them make sense

Comment: I tried different ways, with replace(), translate() or creating 2 strings. but I have always an error of syntax, I am missing something, I can not delete M and N but I can duplicate the character, or delete it, how can I duplicate the previous character ? after delete M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) like so:

```
import re
strings = ['abcNdgM', 'abcdg', 'MrtyNNgMM']

for s in strings:
    # Repeat the cycles of transforming M/N with previous or subsequent characters:
    while True:
        s_new = re.sub(r'N.', '', re.sub(r'(.)M', r'\1\1', s))
        if s == s_new:
            break
        s = s_new
    # Remove any remaining Ms and Ns:
    s = re.sub(r'[MN]+', '', s)
    print(s)
# abcgg
# abcdg
# rtyggg
```

`r'STRING'`: [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).
`.` : any 1 character.
`\1` : capture group 1, that is, whatever was matched by the pattern inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
s ="MrtyNNNgjbM"

a = list(s)

if a[0] =="M":
    a[0] = ""

for i in range(1,len(a)):
    
    if a[i] == 'M':
        if a[i-1] == '':
            j = i-1
            while a[j] == '':
                j-=1
            a[i] = a[j]
        else:
            a[i] = a[i-1]

    if a[i] == "N":
        c = 1
        j = i+1
        a[i] = ''
        while a[j] == "N":
            a[j] = ''
            c+=1
            j+=1
        
        k = j
  
        while c>0:
            a[k] = ''
            c-=1
            k+=1


print(''.join(a))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
def StringChanges(s1: str):
l = list(s1)
i = 0
s2 = ""
while i < len(l):
    if l[i] == 'M':
        if i == 0:
            i += 1
            continue
        s2 += l[i-1]
        l[i] = l[i-1]
        i += 1
    elif l[i] == 'N':
        i += 2
    else:
        s2 += l[i]
        i += 1
return s2
```

s = "MrtyNNgMM"
print(StringChanges(s))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This code doesn't quite conform to the specification (special characters should affect the preceding character, not the following). But more importantly, this post needs an explanation, not just code, in order to help OP understand and learn. See the comment on the other similar answer.

Answer (score -3):

In this python code, `i` is a string, taking on the value of each letter, one at a time, for each iteration through the `for` loop. But in the `cupofprogramming` example you linked, `i` is an integer representing the *position* (index) of a letter through each iteration of the loop. If you want this code to work with the index of each letter, take a look at how the [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function works.